# regex integer identification error python

Tags: python, regex, binary, integer

I am writing laxer for C in python and facing this problem:

This is my function to identify integer:

```
def t_INT_CONSTANT(t):
  r'(\d+ | 0b[0-1]+)'
  t.type = reserved_map.get(t.value,"INT_CONSTANT")
  return t
```

I am using it to identity decimal and binary integers.

The problem is that when expression is 0b101010, it makes 0 int and b101010 identifier (another function defined above this one).

It works well with:

```
#r'(0b[0-1]+ | \d+)'
```

What is the problem with 1st? Why does 2nd work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the chars matched by the first pattern (ie, pattern which exists before to `|`),  won't be matched by the second pattern (*pattern on the right side of `|`*).

If you use `\d+|0b[0-1]+` regex, the first `\d+` should match the `0` which exists just before to `b` in `0b101010`. When the regex engine uses the second pattern , `0b[0-1]+`, it won't find any match..

If you reverse the patterns like  `0b[0-1]+|\d+`, now it checks for `0b[0-1]+` very first. So place the patterns according to the priority. pattern at the left side have higher priority than the one in the right side.